# String replace com array de palavras foreach

Tags: javascript

Preciso que dentro de um `foreach` de um `array` com palavras em cada posição, substituam determinadas palavras dentro de uma string.

Exemplo:

```
array = ["Login", "1234"]
String: "Seu código para [[1]] é [[2]]"
```

Mensagem final:

```
Seu código para Login é 1234.
```

[Forma que fiz nesse momento](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivc3i.png)

Resposta de cada foreach:

[Resultado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZPkd.png)

Meu problema é que o último replace que prevalece, e não com o primeiro, entao minha mensagem final fica:

Seu código para [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivc3i.png)] é 1234.

Como poderia solucionar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente o código é muito trivial, onde o [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) pega por ordem os números de itens do `array` e o números contidos na `string` e substitui dentro do [forEach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp) pela sua indexação somando mais 1, ***exemplo***?

```js
let message = "Seu código para [[1]] é [[2]]";
const array = ["Login", "1234"];
array.forEach(function(item, index) {
  message = message.replace("[[" + (index + 1) + "]]", item);
});
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message;
```

```html
<div id="message"> gerando ...</div>
```

***Referencias:***

- [JavaScript Array forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [JavaScript String replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Comment: Obrigado novic! 

A meu ver, estava praticamente a mesma coisa, porém com array function.

Comment: o seu faltava um `[` e `]` era apenas erro de digitação e quis deixar como resposta porque muitos erram

Comment: A forma correta é com apenas um [ ], porém na formatação não fica correta aqui no stackoverflow e eu não sabia corrigir. 

Na segunda imagem que foi anexado, é mostrado no console.log que ele substituíam às duas palavras, porém mesmo assim era apenas a última substituição que ficava na mensagem final.

Comment: Entendi @bloodbag